# Couldn’t find executable named talker.cpp

Tags: ros, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run catkin_make, talker listener all files are linked and showed build target talker listener 100%. But when i want to run this using rosrun it says "couldn’t find executable named talker". I have changed the code in CmakeLists.txt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385529/couldn%E2%80%99t-find-executable-named-talker.cpp/) by [Babor](https://answers.ros.org/users/83094/babor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Later I solved it. I made some mistake in cmakelist file

---

Originally posted by [Babor](https://answers.ros.org/users/83094/babor/) with karma: 18 on 2021-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-09-16**:
@Babor Congratulations on the solution. Also, sorry for the wrong comment. If you'd like, you can add to your answer what you fixed, which will help others with the same issue.